# SequelizeEagerLoadingError while include: [{model: , as: ' ' }]

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I want to run this function. I want that the included `model: SurveyResult` getting an alias.

But i get this error: SequelizeEagerLoadingError: SurveyResult is associated to User using an alias. You've included an alias (Geburtsdatum), but it does not match the alias defined in your association.

```
 const mediImport = await User.findAll({
        where: { Id: 1 },
        // Select forename as Vorname, name as Nachname
        attributes: [['forename', 'Vorname'], ['name', 'Nachname']],
        include: [{
          model: SurveyResult,
          as: 'Geburtsdatum'
        }]
      })
```

I know that it is a Problem with my associates, but i cant find the problem

Here are my models.

Model: User

```
User.associate = function (models) {
User.hasOne(models.Admin)
User.hasOne(models.UserStatus)
User.hasOne(models.SurveyResult, {
})
```

Model SurveyResult

```
 SurveyResult.associate = function (models) {
    SurveyResult.hasOne(models.Survey)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
User.hasOne(models.SurveyResult, {})
```

You need to **define the alias on the association level** also , like this :

```
User.hasOne(models.SurveyResult,{ as : 'Geburtsdatum' });
```